# C# error: cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions

Tags: c#, delphi, interop

I'm struggling with a C# program to read binary records from a database.  The records were created with Borland Delphi.  Here's an example:

```
// Delphi record definition
  tBowler_Rec = Record
  public
    gender          : tGender;
    bowler_num      : byte;
    name            : tString32;
    initials        : String[3];
    ...
```

```
// Corresponding C# definition (unmanaged code)
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
    public unsafe struct tBowler_Rec
    {
        public tGender gender;
        public byte bowler_num;
        public fixed byte name[32];
        public fixed byte initials[3];
        ...
```

I'm actually able to read this binary struct out of a SQL Server database and see the data in the Visual Studio debugger.  Yay!  I'm able to access fields like "gender" and "bowler_num" with no problem. Yay!

Q: How do I turn "name" into a C# string?

An example name is "ASHTON".  It looks like this in memory:

```
\0x6ASHTON\0x0\0x0...
```

Here's how I'm trying to access it:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
public unsafe struct tBowler_Rec
{
    public tGender gender;
    public byte bowler_num;
    public fixed byte name[32];
    ...
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int ilen = name[0];
            for (int i = 1; i <= ilen; i++)
                sb.Append(name[i]);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error: You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed
> expressions. Try using the fixed statement.

Comment: Why are you using `unsafe` and `fixed`? I don't see why you would need to do that.  It looks like a pretty routine P/Invoke to me.

Comment: Check this question http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/584049-fixed-byte-array-string

Comment: TString32 is a custom type in Delphi, what is it's declaration?   I am guessing String[32].

Comment: Are you really sure you want to send `string[N]` instances between Delphi and C#?

Comment: `\0x6ASHTON\0x0\0x0` clearly is good ol' Turbo Pascal string where length byte prepends up to 255 character bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm not very familiar with Delphi so I can't give you a straight answer on the `tString32` field. It seems to be [UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

If this is the case, I would go for something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
public struct tBowler_Rec
{
    public tGender gender;
    public byte bowler_num;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    public string name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public char[] initials;
```

Look also how I'm doing the `initials` marshaling. If tString is not an AnsiBStr, this would be a better way to marshal the characters from name.

I also would like to show that I've removed the fixed and unsafe instructions from the struct declaration as this is not necessary for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi -You're correct - I definitely want "MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValArray).  The central issue is "reference types" (.Net arrays and classes are both examples of reference types) and "value types" (like .Net structs ... and here, unmanaged array types).  Thanx again for the help!

Comment: @paul Although you have marked this as your answer I'm far from convinced that Delphi short strings are a good choice for interop with .net. In fact I think they are, today, a bad choice for just about anything.

Comment: As if Bstr is a "good choice" ;)?  Remember from my original post: I'm reading binary records (created in Delphi) from a database.  That's the problem.  A combination of StructLayout (both Sequential and Explicit, depending on the record), MarshalAs() and property accessors is the solution :)

Comment: I didn't say `BSTR` was the solution here. It's not. You want `array [0..N-1] of char` on the delphi size and `string` with suitable `MarshalAs` on the C# side. Delphi `shortstring` is most definitely not right for interop.

Comment: I think you're saying I should modify the Delphi code.  I can't :(

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(name, 1, name[0]);
```

Comment: This is correct, it takes into account the first byte being length, which is typical of the `ShortString` datatype in Delphi.

Comment: Paulsm here - the downvote wasn't me, Ben.  I chose a different path besides "GetString()", but I appreciate the feedback.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The string stored in the original format is not "null terminated" ( C style string).

The original format is 'char count Then Count chars 
=>  0x6 = char count, A = 0 S = 1 H = 2 T = 3 O = 4 N = 5.

You try to read Chars until a null char is encountered. But there are no null char, it's not a null terminated string. You have to set a custom data caster for this or to convert the database.

Comment: Good observation that it's length-prefixed.  But you don't need a custom converter, .NET provides the ASCIIEncoding class for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[Fixed size buffer cannot be directly used from "this" object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011980/fixed-size-buffer-cannot-be-directly-used-from-this-object)

Solution:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
public unsafe struct tBowler_Rec
{
    public tGender gender;
    public byte bowler_num;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=32)]
    public byte[] name;
    ...
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int ilen = name[0];
            for (int i = 1; i <= ilen; i++)
                sb.Append(name[i]);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Vladimir was absolutely on the right track: the fundamental problem was that I needed to treat this Delphi array as a value type, not a C# (reference type) array.  The solution is `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)`.